# Android counterpart of iOS memory warning

Tags: android, ios, memory, warnings

In iOS an app will receive a memory warning by implementing a function called `DidReceiveMemoryWarning`, which means the RAM is not enough to use. If a Level 2 version of this warning is sent, the app will probably be force stopped.

Is there something similar (like a broadcast intent) in Android to tell my app that we're out of RAM and i could remove some objects programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should define your own custom application object by extending [Android Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and define that object in the Application tag in the manifest file. In this custom object you can override the [onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29) method.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Note that this doesn't prevent OutOfMemoryErrors. `onLowMemory()` raises when the **system global memory is low**. If the global memory is okay but your process takes more than 24MB on old Android devices, it will crash and you'll never get a low memory warning. I know, it's a shame.

Comment: @cprcrack Thanks a lot for your hint. This is important!