# In a Unity3D - Android project .. how to get memory warnings?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, memory-warning

How to be alerted of memory warnings?  Unity3D, building to Android.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to `Application.lowMemory` [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-lowMemory.html)

For example, in some monoBehaviour starting your game:

```
private void Start() 
{
    Application.lowMemory += ReportSystemLowMemory;
} 


private void ReportSystemLowMemory() 
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Warning: Low memory");
}
```

- Be sure to don't subscribe `ReportSystemLowMemory` more than once.
- Also unsubscribing it would be a good practice, ie `Application.lowMemory -= ReportSystemLowMemory` when you are close your app/game.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function for this in Android as far as I know.

Comment: I see - to be clear, you mean, unrelated to Unity. There is - simply - no memory warning concept in Android?  Is that right?  Thanks so much BTW.

Comment: Wait - what about onTrimMemory and onLowMemory ?  Eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767766/android-counterpart-of-ios-memory-warning

Comment: Those methods are not called prior to an OOM exception. They are called when the overall system is low on memory.